# Null access token for facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

Hi been struggling with this for the past 2 days. I never had the issue before but the access token being returned from facebook is always null no matter what I do.

The code used is from facebook connect IOS sdk. I used the exact same code in other apps but had no issues but for some reason this doesn't work now.

There are also no error codes being printed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use in sessionChangeState, this code:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"access Token %@", FBSession.activeSession.accessToken);
}];
```

And it return me access token, try it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.You will get access token through self.facebook.accessToken .
call facebookbtnclicked method at view did load or anywhere to get access token.

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"227757844008650"];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"])
    {

        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];

    }
-(void)facebookbtnclicked
{
    NSLog(@"facebook btn clicked");
    [self loginToFacebook:self];
}

- (BOOL) isFaceBookLoggedIn
{
    if (self.facebook.accessToken)
    {
        return YES;

    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void) logoutFromFacebook: (id) logoutDelegate
{
    fbServiceRequestingobj = logoutDelegate;
    [facebook logout:self];
}

- (void)loginToFacebook:(id) loginDelegate
{
    NSLog(@"login facebook method");

    fbServiceRequestingobj = loginDelegate;

    NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_stream", nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];

}
-(void) getuserdata
{

    NSLog(@"[appDelegate getuserdata]");

    if (fbServiceRequestingobj) 
    {
        fbServiceRequestingobj = nil;
    }

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];


    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];

}
- (void)fbDidLogout
{
    NSLog(@"Did Logout");

    if (fbServiceRequestingobj)
    {
        if ([fbServiceRequestingobj respondsToSelector:@selector(fbDidLogout)])
        {
            [fbServiceRequestingobj performSelector:@selector(fbDidLogout)];
        }
    }
    fbServiceRequestingobj = nil;
}


- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    if (fbServiceRequestingobj)
    {
        if ([fbServiceRequestingobj respondsToSelector:@selector(request:didFailWithError:)])
        {
            [fbServiceRequestingobj request:request didFailWithError:error];
        }
    }
    fbServiceRequestingobj = nil;
}

-(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled
{

    if (fbServiceRequestingobj)
    {
        if ([fbServiceRequestingobj respondsToSelector:@selector(fbDidNotLogin:)])
        {
            //[fbServiceRequestingobj fbDidNotLogin:cancelled];
        }
    }
    fbServiceRequestingobj = nil;
}


- (void)fbDidLogin
{

    NSLog(@"fbDidLogin");
    //[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
    NSLog(@"accesstoken########%@",self.facebook.accessToken);
}


- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    count++;
    NSError *error = [request error];

    if (!error)
    {
        NSString *response = [request responseString];

        NSDictionary *respdic=[response JSONValue];
        if(![[respdic valueForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:@""])
        {


            UIAlertView *alert1=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Photo posted successfully." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert1 show];
        }
    }
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
{


    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {

        }   


    }
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
    {

        UIImage *profilePicture = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: result];

    }


    if (fbServiceRequestingobj)
    {
        if ([fbServiceRequestingobj respondsToSelector:@selector(request:didLoad:)])
        {
            [fbServiceRequestingobj request:request didLoad:result];
        }
    }

    fbServiceRequestingobj = nil;

};
```

Comment: Cheers I solved it by rewriting everything and using the latest facebook sdk. Still not sure what caused the issue.